# Reading a remote xml file

Tags: java, xml, file

I want to read a xml file that is presnt on a remote location.I use the following code

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inputLine;
String strOutput = "";
System.out.println("start now");
//my code hangs after  priting start now            
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
       strOutput = strOutput + inputLine;
}

//contol doesnot reach here sometimes
in.close();
```

Is this a good way to read a remote file.What is the network is slow?Please suggest

Comment: `"server"` is not a valid URL, it has to be `"http://server/file.xml"` or something like this.

Comment: If network is slow it will take very long to reach `in.close()` that's all (unless there is something else that causes time-out)

Comment: I dont want to wait indefinitely, cant i time out?

Comment: I would recommend not doing `strOutput = strOutput + inputLine;`. This may get quite slow if you're reading large XML files. Instead use a `StringBuilder` and call the `append` method. Adding Strings together like that involves creating a copy of the original String, so as the String gets larger, this will get slower and slower.

Comment: IS my approach of reading file correct?

Comment: @ashkay - try calling in.ready() and checking thats it's return value is true, right before your while loop. Because your code itself looks fine (though as @agxs mentioned, you don't want to build your input string the way you have it now).

Comment: i observed that sometimes by conde gets hanged after calling in.ready.Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The comments have already indicated that there are some poor practices. I'll attempt to list what could be the cause of the poor performance:

- Using `readLine()`. You are assuming that the XML file contains several lines, each terminated by either `\r\n`, `\r` or `\n`. This need not be the case, resulting the scenario where `readLine()` will take quite some time to complete.
- Concatenating `String` objects. Strings are immutable in Java. Concatenating Strings will create a new String object, and this can become expensive if the size of the resulting string is quite large. If your document's ranges from a few bytes to kilobytes, this might not be an issue, but if it runs into megabytes, you are asking for trouble. Use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead.
- Assumptions on network performance. It might be better to fetch the file and parse it, instead of opening a connection, buffering it's contents and then parsing it. The network might simply not be capable of responding to your requests to read the file in a timely manner. By pre-fetching the file, you avoid hitting the network on every `readLine()` that will require reading beyond the buffered contents.

Comment: how can i fetch the entire file at once?This file is obtained by calling a  url of a webserver.

Comment: The same way as you are doing it now. Except that you ought to be writing to a FileOutputStream instead of concatenating to a String. And, better use `read()` instead of `readLine()`. See some of the answers in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using JAXB or other sophesticated XML readers they are optimized in reading XML files.